# Get identity value after insert in entity framework while using dependancy injection

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using entity frame work in my mvc core application. I am also using dependency injection technique. Now i want to get the value of new record identity column. I am using the code as..

```
public interface IGenericRepositoryStudent<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T item);
}

public class GenericRepositoryStudent<T> : IGenericRepositoryStudent<T> where T : class
{
    private eerp_studentContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepositoryStudent(eerp_studentContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    private IStudentRepository _dbSet;

    public StudentController(IStudentRepository dbSet)
    {
        _dbSet = dbSet;
    }

    public long Add([FromBody]Student _student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(acJournal);
            long _id = _student.id; // value of _id is always 0.
            return _id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The id is only backfilled after the object is actually saved to the database, which only happens after calling `SaveChanges`, not after calling `Add`. However, it would be an extremely poor idea to call `SaveChanges` after every call to add, since that will cause a lot more queries to be generated. By default, EF will try to submit all changes at once.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently every T that you want to Add has a Primary Key. You want the value of this primary Key after the T has been added and changes are saved.

This means, that you can't add objects of every class, you can only add classes that have a Primary Key.

The easiest, and a very type safe way (checked by compiler) is to allow only adding of object that have a primary key.

```
// interface of objects that have Id (primary key)
public interface IID
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
}
```

If your database uses another type for primary keys like int, or GUID, use this other type as return type

```
public interface IGenericRepositoryStudent<T> where T : IID
{
    T Add(T item);
}

 public class GenericRepositoryStudent<T> : IGenericRepositoryStudent<T> where T : IID
{
    ...
    public T Add(T itemToAdd)
    {
        T addedItem = _dbSet.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return addedItem
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Student : IID
{
    public long Id {get; set;} // primary key
    ...
}

public class StudentController : Controller
{
    ...
    public T Add([FromBody]Student _student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return _dbSet.Add(_student);
        }
    }
}
```

I chose to return the complete T instead of only the Id, because if you need some of the properties of the added item, you don't need to fetch the item you just added. Besides this is just the return value of DbSet.Add(T)

If you really want, just return the Student's Id.